# Binding 4 Radio buttons using @html.RadioButtonFor MVC4 ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, enums, radiobuttonfor

Here is my ENUM:

```
public enum ValidityTypes : int
{
    [Description("Not Set")]
    None = 0,
    [Description("Zero Validity")]
    ZeroValidity = 1,
    [Description("Life Time Validity")]
    LifeTimeValidity = 2,
    [Description("N Months")]
    NMonths = 3,
    [Description("Rehire Validity in Months")]
    RehireValidity = 4
}
```

Here I set the Model property:

```
public ValidityTypes ValidityType { get; set; }
```

Here is my View:

```
<label><b>Zero Validity:</b></label>
@if (Model.ValidityType == Constant.ValidityTypes.ZeroValidity) 
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ValidityType, "1", new { @id = "validity1", style = "width:50px", @checked = "true" , onClick = "ValidityEnableDisable(this);" })             
}
else
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ValidityType, "1", new { @id = "validity1", style = "width:50px", @checked = "false" , onClick = "ValidityEnableDisable(this);" })             
}
<label><b>Life Time Validity: </b></label>
@if (Model.ValidityType == OneC.BGV.BE.Constant.ValidityTypes.LifeTimeValidity) 
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ValidityType, "2", new { @id = "validity2", style = "width:50px", @checked = "true" , onClick = "ValidityEnableDisable(this);" }) 
}
else
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ValidityType, "2", new { @id = "validity2", style = "width:50px", @checked = "false" , onClick = "ValidityEnableDisable(this);" }) 
}
<label><b>'N' Months:</label>
@if (Model.ValidityType == OneC.BGV.BE.Constant.ValidityTypes.NMonths) 
{ 
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ValidityType, "3", new { @id = "validity3", style = "width:50px", @checked = "true", onClick = "Validity3EnableDisable(this);" ,  autocomplete="off" }) 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ValidityValue, new { id = "NmonthTextbox", style = "width:50px" })
}
else
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ValidityType, "3", new { @id = "validity3", style = "width:50px", @checked = "false" , onClick = "Validity3EnableDisable(this);" ,  autocomplete="off"})
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ValidityValue, new { id = "NmonthTextbox", style = "width:50px", disabled = "true" })
}
```

Now when I am loading this view I am getting `model.Validitytype` as `ZeroValidity` which is same as in the Database and satisfying the first `if` condition. But on complete view load the `N months` radio button is coming checked.

Why I am not able to show correct radio button selected?
Is it my `@checked` property of the control is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checked="true"` or `checked="false"` or `checked="anythingAtAll"` all mean the same thing - the radio button will be checked. The `checked` attribute is a `boolean` attribute which means its the presence of it that determines if its checked. In your case the last one is always checked because that is the last one that is rendered (the attribute is removed from the previous ones because only one is allowed to be checked).

You should never set the `checked` attribute because the `RadioButtonFor()` method does that based on the value of the model you binding to (that is how model binding works). Remove all your `if/else` blocks and change the code to simply be

```
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ValidityType, ValidityTypes.ZeroValidity, new { id = "", @class = "validity" })
    <span>Zero Validity</span>
</label>
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ValidityType, ValidityTypes.LifeTimeValidity, new { id = "", @class = "validity" })
    <span>Life Time Validity</span>
</label>
// labels below omitted for brevity
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ValidityType, ValidityTypes.NMonths, new { id = "", @class = "validity" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ValidityType, ValidityTypes.RehireValidity, new { id = "", @class = "validity" })
```

Then use css to style your elements rather than inline styles, e.g.

```
.validity {
    width: 50px;
}
```

and use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to handle your events

```
$('.validity').click(function() {
    ....
});
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen for such quick response. But this is a view which gets loaded as pop up on click of a hyperlink. there are 10 items on a page and and each of them has its own validity. so when I click on the hyperlink related to one item I get the validity details for the same.

Comment: That makes no difference at all

Comment: So just want to confirm if this will work for the same? 
On complete load it will show you the saved value of the validity for that item and on the same pop up if i want to change the validity I should be able to save the new value.

Also as you said to remove all **if else**, I still need for showing text boxes

Comment: Your text box does not make any sense either (disabled controls do not post back a value so its pointless). And you did not show what your `ValidityEnableDisable` script was but if that is disabling controls as its name suggests then your making even more mistakes.

Comment: Yes it will shown the correct radio button selected based on the value of the `ValidityType` property in the model. (and I assume you mean that your calling a server method using ajax to load a partial view of the model in the DOM?)

Comment: Then that will bind correctly and select the correct radio button.

Comment: And if you do not want the textbox to be editable, then make it `readonly`, not `disabled`

Comment: If you have a new question about your textbox, then you need to ask a **new** question (not edit this one)